# Need to have 4 results show up on one out-gridview instead of 4 separate ones

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works pretty well until I need to output the results to one out-gridview instead of four.  Please advise.

```
$Date = (Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy")

$FileContent = Get-Content "c:\temp\$date.txt"
$AdminMatches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "Administrative" -AllMatches
$AdminMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60 | Out-GridView

$ProjectMatches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "Project" -AllMatches
$ProjectMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60 | Out-GridView

$SustainMatches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "Sustain" -AllMatches
$SustainMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60 | Out-GridView

$PaidMatches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "Paid" -AllMatches
$PaidMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60 | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an object that collects all your counts  and then pipe that to `out-gridview`:

```
[pscustomobject]@{"adminCount" = $AdminMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60; "projectMatches" = $ProjectMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60; "sustainMatchesCount" = $SustainMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60; "paidMatchedCount" = $PaidMatches.Matches.Count * 15 / 60;} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for @zdan

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic method (you can modify you words list and its still work). And search in file is only one executed (better for performance):

```
$File ="c:\temp\{0:MM-dd-yyyy}.txt" -f (Get-Date)
$words="Administrative","Project","Sustain","Paid"

$Countvalues=Select-String $File -Pattern ($words -join "|") -AllMatches | %{ $_.Matches.Groups} | group Value

$Objet=[pscustomobject]@{}

foreach ($word in $words)
{
 $Nb=($Countvalues | where name -eq $word).Count / $words.Count
 $Objet | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $word -Value $Nb    
}

$Objet | Out-GridView
```